# Process and return data from a group of a group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, feature-engineering

I have a pandas dataframe of 3 variables, 2 categorical and 2 numeric.

| ID | Trimester | State | Tax | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | T1 | NY | 20 | 0.25 |
| 23 | T3 | FL | 34 | 0.3 |
| 35 | T2 | TX | 45 | 0.6 |

I would like to get a new table of the form:

| ID | Trimester | State | Tax | rate | Tax_per_state_per_trimester |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | T1 | NY | 20 | 0.25 | H |
| 23 | T3 | FL | 34 | 0.3 | L |
| 35 | T2 | TX | 45 | 0.6 | M |

where the new variable 'Tax_per_state_per_trimester' is a categorical variable representing the tertiles of the corresponding subgroup, where L = first tertile, M = second tertile, L = last tertile

I understand I can do a double grouping with:

df.groupby(['State', 'Trimester'])

but i don't know how to go from there.

I guess apply or transform with the quantile function should prove useful, but how?

Comment: Can use pd.quantile(0.33) ? But what is the based of you tertile ? By the time you groupby trimester, state, you would have only 1 tax value ? Then what is the base to calculate the tertile ? base is all trimester or all state ?  I counldn't figure out.

Comment: There would not bet just 1 tax value because the dataframe is much bigger, that was just a sample. The double grouping would give (before any operation) a  list with the tax values of each state on each trimester. For example the group NY_T1 would have [20,45,65,75] and then normaly a function is applied, eg. mean(). If I wanted that then I would just do df.groupby(['State', 'Trimester'])['tax'].mean() and I would get the mean tax per state per trimester.

Comment: .mean() would you just 1 number.  What you want is say  [20,45,65,75,xx,xx,xx] and for each state, tri, you want a quantile, right ?  Won't be just 1 number, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look and see if this gives you the results you want ?

```
df = pd.read_excel('Tax.xlsx')
```

[image]

```
def mx(tri,state):
    return df[(df['Trimester'].eq(tri)) & (df['State'].eq(state))] \
    .groupby(['Trimester','State'])['Tax'].apply(max)[0]

for i,v in df.iterrows():
    t = (v['Tax'] / mx(v['Trimester'],v['State']))
    df.loc[i,'Tax_per_state_per_trimester'] = 'L' if t < 1/3 else 'M' if t < 2/3 else 'H'
```

[image]

Comment: @dov1000.  I put this up to see if this is the result you looking for. I think if your table is small, the code is ok.  But might be slow if large.